# How to pass data between the screens of a tab navigator, when pressing a button in the 1st screen and WITHOUT being routed to the 2nd screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a bottom tab navigator with 2 screens: Screen1 and Screen2.

In Screen1, there's a FlatList which displays the content of the "fruits" list:
It consists of an item and an "add" button next to it.
when the button is pressed the item is displayed in Screen2.

I want to pass an item from the "fruits" list in Screen1 when pressing the "add" button, to Screen2, without being automatically routed to Screen2.

Until now I was able to pass the item from Screen1 to Screen2 using: navigation.navigate("Screen2", {item}), but it automatically takes me to Screen2, which is not what I want.

I think the dispatch method of the navigation prop can solve this issue, but I don't know how to use it!

I'm using React Native 0.65 and React Navigation 6.x.

Here's the official documentation of the dispatch method:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dispatch

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const fruits = [
  'apples',
  'watermelons',
  'tomatoes',
  'pomegranates',
  'strawberries'
];

function Screen1({ navigation }) {
  const renderItems = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.item_container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
        <Button 
          title="add"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2', { item })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={fruits}
        renderItem={renderItems}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function Screen2({ route }) {
  const { item } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text  style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Screen1"
          component={Screen1}
           options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Screen 1',
           }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Screen2"
          component={Screen2}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Screen 2',
          }}
        />
     </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  item_container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: 5,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    margin: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you thought about using Redux? or other state management libraries?

Comment: That's something to be handled via context / state management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers! In fact, Redux was the solution and I was able to implement the code.

Here is the solution :)

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const fruits = ['apples', 'watermelons', 'tomatoes', 'pomegranates',  'strawberries'];

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return 'nothing!';
  }
  if (action.type === 'addItem') {
    return action.value.item;
  }
  return state;
}

const store = createStore(combineReducers({ selectedItem: reducer }));

function Screen1({ selectedItem }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(store.getState());
  }, [selectedItem]);

  const renderItems = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.item_container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
        <Button
          title="add"
          onPress={() =>
            store.dispatch({
              type: 'addItem',
              value: { item }
            })
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>My favorite fruits:</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={fruits}
        renderItem={renderItems}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function Screen2({ selectedItem }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>You selected {selectedItem}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

// Connect the screens to Redux
const Screen1Container = connect((state) => ({
  selectedItem: state.selectedItem,
}))(Screen1);
const Screen2Container = connect((state) => ({
  selectedItem: state.selectedItem,
}))(Screen2);

// Create the stack navigator
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Screen1"
            component={Screen1Container}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: 'Screen 1',
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Screen2"
            component={Screen2Container}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: 'Screen 2',
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    //justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 25,
  },
  item_container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginVertical: 7,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 7,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since you are using react native which uses the native APIs underneath and you aren't using a webview, so you are allowed to do only what the native iOS & Android behavior is.

Natively in Android, the 2 inactive tabs (to the left and to the right) next to the active tab render as soon as that active tab opens. So when you tap on the next tab, it doesn't really have to do any other work which allows it to load quickly.

Therefore you would have to take advantage of a `state` management library. Whenever a stateful property is updated, it forces a re-render of the page where it is used. So, if you assign a new value in one tab, it should automatically refresh the UI in any adjacent page with the new value.